# Trying to lock database but not working

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a table that looks like this

```
Create Table Items(
   [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   [UniqueCol] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
   [Col] int NOT NULL
)

ALTER TABLE Items ADD CONSTRAINT UN_UniqueCol UNIQUE(UniqueCol)
```

I have a stored procedure in sql server 2008 that looks like this.

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
BEGIN TRANSACTION

if not exists(select * from Items where UniqueCol=uniqueval)
begin
    insert into Items (UniqueCol, Col) values (uniqueval, val)
end
select * from Items where UniqueCol = uniqueval
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

EDIT: THIS Merge works correctly

```
MERGE INTO Items as Target USING (VALUES(uniqueval)) as source (UniqueCol)
on (source.UniqueCol = Target.UniqueCol)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   update set col = val
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target THEN
    insert (UniqueCol, col) VALUES (uniqueval, val);
```

I am running a website in asp.net mvc that hits this procedure very often. The reason I'm doing this in a stored proc is that I thought it was the easiest place to handle the concurrency issues that were occurring when 2 things tried to insert the same thing at the same time.

The select at the end is somehow returning a value to my model in asp.net mvc. I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do this, but it works when I try to call the stored procedure from the webserver

This stored procedure is called very often, and potentially with 2 of the same thing at the same time. The unique key prevents bad data from being stored, but I'd like to not have to commit and catch a unique key exception to handle concurrent inserts when they do happen. Can I lock the table without killing performance here?

I was assuming that this would lock Items so that 2 requests couldn't try to insert into it at the same time, (and cause duplicate id's) and they couldn't try to insert the same value into the table twice (2 rows with UniqueCol=uniqueval)

Am I doing this incorectly? I just tried calling this stored proc in parallel a few times and one gave me an error saying there was a duplicate PK violation.

It seems like set transaction isolation level isn't meant to lock tables in this way. Can someone explain what it is meant for and also the correct way to lock the table for this type of transaction?

Comment: I'd have expected "Id" to be declared a primary key.

Comment: oh sorry, it is. I forgot to put that in.

Comment: The `INSERT` command **only** locks the row(s) it's freshly inserting - nothing else. It doesn't lock the whole table - and that's a *good thing*! Otherwise, performance would suffer horribly....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to get the MERGE to work.

But here is the fix to your problem using your original solution:

The problem is you are using the locking semantics the same way it is used in multi-threading programming. It is a bit different. Two serialized transactions are guaranteed that reads stays the same for the duration of the transaction as seen the moment each transaction started, respectively.

So user1 with T1 starts and he sees the value as not created, so he starts create a new row. User2 with T2, starts while T1 is not yet committed (i.e. in the middle), it will start to read the value.
Because T1 is not committed yet, the value is isolated and won't be seen by T2/user2, and therefore will try to insert a new row too.

Both transactions will try to create two rows with the value.

To have your logic work as you intended it, you need to set the transaction isolation level to: READ UNCOMMITTED.
What this would do, would allow T2 to see the changes done by T1, even before T1 gets committed.
Add another read after the Insert. If it is the same value as the current, then go ahead and commit, otherwise rollback. This effectively "Optimistic concurrency" but implemented by you on the SQL level. You could do it on the application level as well.

```
USE mytstdb;
-- This also applies the spirit of the double-checked locking pattern/concept
-- It also applies optimistic concurrency
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
BEGIN TRANSACTION

DECLARE @uniqueval NVARCHAR(20) = 'unique value';
DECLARE @val INT = 10;

DECLARE @valCount INT;

-- This is a dirty read, but for what you need it is OK
SET @valCount = (select count(*) from Items where UniqueCol=@uniqueval);
if(@valCount = 0)
begin
    insert into Items (UniqueCol, Col) values (@uniqueval, @val)
    SET @valCount = (select count(*) from Items where UniqueCol=@uniqueval);
    -- Optimistic concurrency
    if(@valCount > 1)
    begin
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        return;
    end
end

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried using merge but i'm seeing the same duplicate PK violation. Any idea why that might happen? I'll put my merge command in the question

Comment: I got merge working. My source made no sense. I edited the question to show what the source should have been

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, [serializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) isolation is documented as having the following behavior.

> - Statements cannot read data that has been modified but not yet
>     committed by other transactions.
> - No other transactions can modify data that has been read by the
>     current transaction until the current transaction completes.
> - Other transactions cannot insert new rows with key values that
>     would fall in the range of keys read by any statements in the current
>     transaction until the current transaction completes.

Serializable isolation doesn't lock tables.

I believe that, when your `if not exists` clause fails, your transaction isn't reading any data. (It fails because the id you're presumably looking for doesn't exist.) So there are no locks acquired by this SELECT.

You can lock a table with a [TABLOCK table hint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), but I don't think I've ever seen anyone do that in real life. It's bad for concurrent access.

You can probably get a better answer by editing your question and including information about all the candidate keys (not just the primary key), and about why you think you need to lock the table.  Your very best bet, as always with SQL questions, is to include SQL DDL for your tables. DDL is the most accurate description possible; it's worth more than a thousand words.

Comment: yes, i read that and it sounded like what I wanted. I guess it's not. Can you suggest how do lock it properly?

Comment: I renmaed blah and whatever to be more descriptive.

Comment: also, the behavior says "Other transactions cannot insert new rows...." Isn't that locking?

Comment: Read it again; it doesn't say that. It says, "Other transactions cannot insert new rows with key values that would fall in the range of keys **read** by any statements in the current transaction."  If you're inserting a new key, you can't possibly have read it.

Comment: ah, got it. So is there a way to safely lock for what i'm trying to do?

Comment: I updated the question with some more info. One thing that confuses me is why the insertions would both try to insert a row with the same id, instead of different ids but the same value in colname.